# Spring MVC add and remove levels in URL

Tags: java, spring

I encoutered problem when adding another level in my request mapping URL. Here is the details:

I have a first page: A, and corresponding controller A with request mapping of `A`. (RequestMapping="A")

From Page A, user can go to two supplemental pages: B, C. These two pages are very trivial, and collect supplemental information for Page A. Once user are done with Page B and C, they will return to A.

So I added B and C as additional level on top of A.(To reflect this logic relation) Their URL lookes like: `http://contextRoot/A/B`, and `http://contextRoot/A/C`
Controller for page B and C has request mapping `A/B` and `A/C`.

**The Problem Is: ** I find that I could not return to the previous level of URL. For example, in controller B and C, if I return a view using `redirect:D` (`D` is another page after `A`), it will redirect me to `http://contextRoot/A/D`, instead of `http://contextRoot/D`.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try `redirect:../D`.

Comment: Take in consideration `Spring Web Flow` too, where flow process among pages are well covered there.

Comment: URI are relative, use `../A` to go up once, or `/A` to use absolute paths.